# A Poisson random variable that can't take a value of $0$

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

The question is as follows:

The number of eggs laid on a tree leaf by an insect of a certain type is a Poisson random variable with parameter $λ$. However, such a random variable can only be observed if it is positive, since if it is $0$ then we cannot know that such an insect was on the leaf. If we let $X$ denote a Poisson distributed random variable with parameter $λ$ and $Y$ denote the observed number of eggs, then $P(Y = i) = P(X = i|X > 0)$ where $X$ is Poisson with parameter $λ$. Find $E[Y]$.

Now the answer is:

$\frac{λ}{1-e^{-λ}}$

My question is: why did we have to consider the random variable $X$ in the first place; because if we were to calculate the expected value of $Y$ normally, we will start the summation from $i=1$ to infinity, so we shouldn't worry about $Y$ taking a value of $0$, I know my thinking is flawed so please help me understand, thanks in advance!

***EDIT***

I think it might be because the probability distribution has changed, because even though $0$ can be ignored when calculating the expected value, it still has a probability which is equal to $e^{-λ}$, having this probability equal $0$ (since $0$ isn't in the domain of $Y$) will have an effect on all other probabilities for all values of $Y$. Is this right?

Comment: Your title is wrong. The probability that a Poisson variable takes the value zero is $e^{-\lambda}\,.$ To the body: Ignoring all the stuff I don't understand: "The number of eggs laid on a tree leaf by an insect of a certain type is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda\,.$ [...] $Y$
  denote the observed number of eggs. [...] Find $E[Y]\,.$" Hint: look up Poisson distribution in Wikipedia. Since you are asking the same questions like me: Where does that nonsense with $X$ come from?

Comment: It is stated in the problem that the number of eggs laid $Y$ IS a Poisson random variable, the only twist is that $Y$ can't be equal to zero, normally a Poisson random variable takes values from $0$ to infinity, so I don't see why the title might be wrong.

Comment: in other words $P(Y=0)=0$.

Comment: I repeat: a Poisson random variable $Y$ takes the value zero with probability $e^{-\lambda}\,.$ If you don't want $Y$ to take the value zero you have to choose $\lambda=+\infty$ obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model being applied in this question is called a "zero-truncated" Poisson distribution.

There are two random variables described:
$$X \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda), \\ \Pr[X = x] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}, \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$$
models the random number of eggs laid on a leaf, given that a (gravid) insect has visited that leaf.  Theoretically, if you could watch such an insect--perhaps in a controlled enclosed environment--you might be able to observe landings in which no eggs were laid.

However, if we are observing eggs on leaves in nature, and we cannot observe or track the movements of such insects directly, then we cannot simply count all leaves with zero eggs, because we don't know if an insect has visited that leaf.  So the observational data that we collect only contains data on the number of leaves we counted that had at least one egg, and for each such leaf, we count the number of eggs on it.

The random variable $Y$, which models the observed data, is *not* Poisson.  It is given by
$$Y = \begin{cases} X, & X > 0 \\ \text{undefined}, & X = 0. \end{cases}$$  In particular, the support of $Y$ is on the strictly positive integers $Z^+ = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$.  Note that although the variable $X$ exists in principle, we are not able to always observe it.  We can only observe $Y$.  The distribution that $Y$ follows is called a zero-truncated Poisson.

We can calculate
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y = y] &= \Pr[X = y \mid X > 0] \\
&= \frac{\Pr[(X = y) \cap (X > 0)]}{\Pr[X > 0]} \\
&= \frac{\Pr[X = y] \mathbb 1 (y \in \mathbb Z^+)}{1 - \Pr[X = 0]} \\
&= \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{1 - e^{-\lambda}} \frac{\lambda^y}{y!} \mathbb 1 (y \in \mathbb Z^+). \end{align}$$
This gives the PDF of the zero-truncated distribution of $Y$.  You can easily use it to calculate the expectation $\operatorname{E}[Y]$.  Is it equal to the expected value of $X$?  Why or why not?

---

Now suppose we have observed a sample from $Y$, namely
$$\boldsymbol Y = (y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots, y_n),$$ where each $y_i$ is some positive integer that records the number of eggs on the $i^{\rm th}$ leaf that we saw that contained at least one egg, and we observed $n$ such leaves in total.

Under the zero-truncated Poisson model, how would we go about using this information to estimate the probability that an insect lands on a leaf but does not lay any eggs?

Comment: very nice answer.

Comment: -"Is it equal to the expected value of $X$? Why or why not?" It's not, because as you mentioned in your answer the PMF for $X$ is different than $Y$'s, hence their expected values will not be the same. It's what I meant in my edit, only I phrased to the best of my understanding.

Comment: -"how would we go about using this information to estimate the probability that an insect lands on a leaf but does not lay any eggs?" That was a wonderful thought-provoking question, I thought about it for a while, and the best I came up with is that we need more *specific* information, maybe information about the species itself, or as you mentioned, maybe we can compare the values of $Y$ to another random variable values in which we had a controlled environment and could actually observe landings with no laid eggs, then we can study the trends and predict the required probability.

Comment: I'm very eager to hear what you have to say about my *silly* guess for your second question, and thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @AbdoIsmail You are most welcome.  As for the estimation question, what comes to my mind is that one could take the expression you obtain for expected value of $Y$, which will be a function of the parameter $\lambda$, and set it equal to the sample mean of the observed data.  Then you would solve the resulting equation for $\lambda$, which would give you an estimate of the Poisson rate parameter.  Then the probability that an insect lands on a leaf but lays no eggs would be $\Pr[X = 0] = e^{-\lambda}$, where we use the estimated $\lambda$ since the real one is unknown to us.

Comment: However, you are quite correct that more specific information could be helpful, because the assumptions underlying the use of a zero-truncated Poisson model for the egg-laying behavior are some rather strong ones.  There's no reason to believe, for instance, that the "land-but-no-eggs-laid" probability should obey a Poisson distribution in the first place, because even if the egg counts when an insect does lay eggs might obey such a distribution, the zero case might be special.  If so, more information is needed, and we might need to use a **zero-modified** Poisson model instead.